# Laravel route after the last hyphen

Tags: php, laravel

Say I have the following url:

```
/blog/this-is-a-post-20
```

and I want to separate it like this:

```
$urlTitle = "this-is-a-post";
$id = 20;
```

I'm currently trying the following:

```
Route::get('blog/{urlTitle}-{id}', function($urlTitle, $id)
```

But it's not working and it gives me:

```
$urlTitle = "this";
$id = "-is-a-post-20"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Route::get('blog/{urlTitle}-{id}', function($urlTitle, $id) {
    var_dump($urlTitle); // this-is-a-post
    var_dump($id);       // 20
})->where('urlTitle', '.*');
```

This will make `urlTitle` match the regular expression of 0+ characters.  Expressions try to match *as much as possible*.  That means it will first try to match `this-is-a-post-20` and fail because the route can't continue to match `-{id}`.  It "backtracks" until it can find the `-{id}` also.

To make this more efficient, replace the `.*` regex with [`.*(?=-)`](http://regex101.com/r/pF6lV8) which will match 0+ characters followed by a `-`.  This will reduce the number of times the regular expression engine needs to backtrack.

Comment: For anyone wondering why this still doesn't work, enter `php artisan route:cache` after every change to `web.php`.